# Update Value from Reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm Working with Sql server 2008 i have two tables and one reference table.table1 contains ,

```
        Id  Name    test1   test2
        1    sss    started processing
        2   asdfasd started processing
```

table 2 contains,

```
       Id   Name    test1   test2
       1    sss      2        2
       2    asdfasd  3        2
```

reference table has ,

```
      code  Name 
        1   Started
        2   processing
        3   stopped
```

i have to write update query to change the table 2 values as following,

```
       Id   Name    test1   test2
        1   sss      1       2
        2   asdfasd  1       2
```

how to write update query for the above scenario?

Comment: Based on Table1 data, do you need to update Table2?

Answer (score 1):

Please find example below.

You can do this in one `UPDATE`

```
DECLARE @table1 Table (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100), test1 VARCHAR(100), test2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT 1, 'sss', 'started', 'processing'
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT 2, 'asdfasd', 'started', 'processing'

DECLARE @table2 Table (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100), test1 INT, test2 INT)

INSERT INTO @table2 SELECT 1, 'sss', 2, 2
INSERT INTO @table2 SELECT 2, 'asdfasd', 3, 2

DECLARE @refTable Table (CODE INT, NAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @refTable SELECT 1, 'Started'
INSERT INTO @refTable SELECT 2, 'processing'
INSERT INTO @refTable SELECT 3, 'stopped'


UPDATE T2
SET test1 = R1.Code,
    test2 = R2.Code
FROM @table2 T2
INNER JOIN @table1 T1
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN @refTable R1
    ON T1.test1 = R1.Name
INNER JOIN @refTable R2
    ON T1.test2 = R2.Name

SELECT * 
FROM @table2
```